# React-Native: After destructing state variable became read-only

Tags: react-native, destructuring

I have a state declaration as follows,

```
 class ServicecallsList extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             AllRequestsArr: []
         }
     }
 }
```

some where in the class I am destructing this variable and assigning an empty array based on some condition like this,

```
 const { allRequestsArr } = this.state;
 if(!allRequestsArr)
      allRequestsArr = [];
```

If i do so I am getting an error a shown below,

> Errro: "allRequestsArr" is read-only

But, If i use complete variable name like `this.state.allRequestsArr`, then there would be no issue.

Am I doing anything wrong with destructing? If so, Please correct me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `const` keyword. If you replace it with `let`, your code will work as expected.

Comment: This does not result in changing the value of the class variable.  Destructing just copies the value to a new variable.  Changing that new variable does not change value of the class variable.